# Unable to add Datagrid or GridView in Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating an app for Windows Phone 7. It's kind of searching train details. I did almost everything that fetching data from DB but I am unable to add datagrid or gridview in my application.

The problem is I am unable to add these two controls in my Toolbox. Please give me some suggestion or work around if it is not possible. Also I have to show the details of each row once I click on ID.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. That link basically suggests this [article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-DataGrid-Control-for-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-Part-1.aspx). While it is a workable way it also means huge amount of work, see my comments to the mentioned article.

As a developer working on the inclusion of DataGrid into Resco MobileForms Toolkit I'd like to ask you if you expect any advanced features from the DataGrid. Things such as grouping, column freezing will have to be stripped off.